# FormRequest method to ignore null field upon validation in L5.4

Tags: php, laravel, validation, httprequest, laravel-5.4

I've a Form Request with this rule:

```
"password" => "confirmed"
```

This solution works well in L5.3 because the rule itself has a bug, if you pass two empty fields like

```
"password" => "",
"password_confirmation" => ""
```

they will be validated because both are empty strings (`""`).
Even though this is a bug, I guess, it's fine in a certain degree because my application does other checks after the request anyway but in L5.4 every empty fields are converted to `null` and the `"confirmed"` rule alone does not work anymore because of the new middleware.

I tried:

```
"password" => "sometimes|confirmed"
```

but it does not work because the key exists.

My question is simple:

> Is there a validation rule that works similar to `sometimes` but it checks nullable values instead?

I would like to keep the middleware though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `nullable` validation rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-nullable

Comment: Can you provide an example?

How should I use it in my case?

"password" => "nullable|confirmed" ?

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta Yes.